# U-net: the loss function. The code implemented in Caffe

Tags: conv-neural-network, caffe, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I read the article about U-net. In that paper, the output shape is 384*384, bute the label shape in the dataset is 512*512(same with input shape). I want to know how to define the loss function. 
And I searched some implementation in other deep learning arhictecture, like Keras. But I found they used "padding", so the output shape is same with input (512*512) and the loss function is just simple MSE.

So I really want to know the detail about the way to implemente loss function in Unet.

Comment: And I also see split and merge operation in the implementation of U-net in Keras. But I didn't read anything about split and merge in the architeture. I want to really understand how to use U-net?
I post the keras implementation link:[link](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet)